# How to create multi-value, multi-bundle entity reference fields in code?

Tags: entities

I'm looking for example *code* that demonstrates creating a new entity reference field with multiple values, referring to *multiple different bundles*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for the long code dump but there's really no other way to do this:

```
field_create_field(array(
  'translatable' => '0',
  'entity_types' => array(),
  'settings' => array(
    'target_type' => 'node',
    'handler' => 'base',
    'handler_submit' => 'Change handler',
    'handler_settings' => array(
      'target_bundles' => array(
        'article' => 'article',
        'page' => 'page',
        'webform' => 'webform',
      ),
      'sort' => array(
        'type' => 'none',
        'property' => 'nid',
        'field' => 'body:value',
        'direction' => 'ASC',
      ),
      'behaviors' => array(
        'views-select-list' => array(
          'status' => 0,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'storage' => array(
    'type' => 'field_sql_storage',
    'settings' => array(),
    'module' => 'field_sql_storage',
    'active' => '1',
    'details' => array(
      'sql' => array(
        'FIELD_LOAD_CURRENT' => array(
          'field_data_field_entity_reference' => array(
            'target_id' => 'field_entity_reference_target_id',
          ),
        ),
        'FIELD_LOAD_REVISION' => array(
          'field_revision_field_entity_reference' => array(
            'target_id' => 'field_entity_reference_target_id',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'foreign keys' => array(),
  'indexes' => array(
    'target_id' => array(
      'target_id',
    ),
  ),
  'field_name' => 'field_entity_reference',
  'type' => 'entityreference',
  'module' => 'entityreference',
  'active' => '1',
  'locked' => '0',
  'cardinality' => '-1',
  'deleted' => '0',
  'columns' => array(
    'target_id' => array(
      'description' => 'The id of the target entity.',
      'type' => 'int',
      'unsigned' => TRUE,
      'not null' => TRUE,
    ),
  ),
  'bundles' => array(
    'node' => array(
      'page',
    ),
  ),
));
```

The `target_bundles` in the `handler_settings` is where you assign the different bundles, and the `cardinality` of `-1` ensures unlimited values for the field.

In case you're interested, this is the code that allowed me to build the above definition from an existing entity reference field (which seems to have originated at [this blog post](http://steindom.com/articles/exporting-and-creating-field-definitions-drupal-7)):

```
$entity_type = 'node';
$field_name = 'field_entity_reference';
$bundle_name = 'article';

$info_config = field_info_field($field_name);
$info_instance = field_info_instance($entity_type, $field_name, $bundle_name);
unset($info_config['id']);
unset($info_instance['id'], $info_instance['field_id']);
include_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/utility.inc';
$output = "field_create_field(" . drupal_var_export($info_config) . ");\n";
$output .= "field_create_instance(" . drupal_var_export($info_instance) . ");";
drupal_set_message("<textarea rows=30 style=\"width: 100%;\">". $output .'</textarea>');
```

It's a handy little script; I'm sure I've posted it somewhere here before but I can't find it at the moment.

Comment: I've seen the same script before (and commented on it to) ... I saw it first at this [blog post](http://steindom.com/articles/exporting-and-creating-field-definitions-drupal-7)

Comment: @tenken Thanks I always wondered where I got that from; now I can provide proper attribution